# ¿Como redireccionar hacia un activity y eliminar la pila de actividades android xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.android

vengo a hacerles una consulta, tengo 3 activity, el primero es activity login que cuando inicia sesion se direcciona al activity menu y de alli me voy al activity carga reclamos; lo que yo quiero hacer que desde el activity carga reclamo me redireccione hacia el activity menu cuando se guarde dicho reclamo, pero cual es el tema, me queda la pila de actividades, yo quiero que valla desde el activity carga reclamo hacia el activity menu directo y nose como resolverlo. espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya muchas gracias

asi paso de una actividad a la otra:

```
Intent secondActivityIntentParcelable = new Intent(this, typeof(ActivityMenu));
            secondActivityIntentParcelable.PutExtra("usuarioNombre", stUsuNombre);
            secondActivityIntentParcelable.PutExtra("usuarioId", stIdusuario);
            secondActivityIntentParcelable.PutExtra("usuarioIdRol", stIdRol);
            secondActivityIntentParcelable.PutExtra("NombreCompleto", stnombre + " " + stapellido);
            secondActivityIntentParcelable.PutExtra("email", stEmail);

            StartActivity(secondActivityIntentParcelable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el "activity menu" deberías hacer un `Finish()` para volver al activity anterior.

Y quizás te convenga hacer un finish desde la actividad de login una vez que hiciste el `StartActivity` hacia el menu, para no tener en la pila de actividades la del login